# Dynamically-loading interactive table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, beginner, mysql

I've got a page on a website that shows a table, and upon clicking on a row in the table, it can dynamically load in more results. I am new to jQuery though.

**index.php page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Knife kills</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#list tr").bind("click", function(event) {
                    //Get clicked row
                    var clickedRow = $("#list tr#" + this.id);

                    //Increase clicks
                    if (!$(clickedRow).data("clicks")) {
                        $(clickedRow).data("clicks", 0);
                    }
                    $(clickedRow).data("clicks", $(clickedRow).data("clicks") + 1);

                    //Check if detailed information has been retrieved
                    if ($(clickedRow).data("detailed")) {
                        if ($(clickedRow).data("clicks") % 2 == 0) {
                            //Hide
                            $("#list tr#" + this.id + "row").remove();
                        }
                        else {
                            //Show
                            $($(clickedRow).data("detailed")).insertAfter($(clickedRow));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var loading = $("<tr><td colspan=3>Loading...</td></tr>");
                        loading.insertAfter($(clickedRow));
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "ajax_detailed.php",
                            data: {
                                id: this.id
                            },
                            success: function(html) {
                                if (html) {
                                    //Success
                                    $(loading).remove();
                                    $(html).insertAfter($(clickedRow));
                                    $(clickedRow).data("detailed", html);
                                }
                                else {
                                    //Error
                                    $(loading).remove();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="list">
            <tr><th>#</th><th>Player</th><th>Kills</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "bf4", "bf4") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bf4") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT p.playerId AS pid, p.playerName AS name, COUNT(`playerkills`.`id`) AS amount FROM `playerkills` JOIN players p ON playerkills.playerId = p.playerId WHERE weaponId = 9 GROUP BY playerkills.playerId ORDER BY amount DESC;") or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$lastamount = -1;
$offset = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    if ($lastamount != $result->amount) {
        $i += 1 + $offset;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    else {
        $offset++;
    }
    echo "\t\t\t<tr id='{$result->pid}' style='cursor: pointer;'><td>".$i."</td><td>".$result->name."</td><td>".$result->amount."</td><td></td><td></td></tr>\n";
    $lastamount = $result->amount;
}
mysql_close($con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**ajax_detailed.php page:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "bf4", "bf4") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bf4") or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

echo "<tr id='{$id}row'><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Target</th><th>Kills</th></tr>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT p.playerName AS name, COUNT(`playerkills`.`id`) AS amount FROM `playerkills` JOIN players p ON playerkills.targetId = p.playerId WHERE weaponId = 9 AND playerkills.playerId = '{$id}' GROUP BY playerkills.targetId ORDER BY amount DESC;");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    echo "<tr id='{$id}row'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>".$result->name."</td><td>".$result->amount."</td></tr>";
}

mysql_close($con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I have the feeling that my jQuery is way too complicated.  I hope others can shed light on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic things (looking only the at the JS)

- Don't keep repeating `$(clickedRow)` - `clickedRow` is already a jQuery object. There's no need to use `$()` again.
- Avoid manually tracking a number to figure out whether to hide or show the details. Easier to check if the details are present or not and proceed accordingly.

Functionality-wise, there are *a lot* of ways to do what you need. I'd suggest breaking things out into functions, and a lot of other stuff.

But I don't want to go too far from your current code, so here's a simple, "light" refactoring (and [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9YYWj/))

```
$(function() { // same as $(document).ready()
  $("#list tr").on("click", function (event) { // use .on() instead of .bind() (since jQuery 1.7)
    // Get relevant rows, the simpler way
    var xhr,
        id = this.id,
        clickedRow = $(this),
        loadingRow = clickedRow.next(".loading"),
        detailsRow = clickedRow.next("#" + id + "row");

    if(loadingRow.length > 0) {
      return; // stop here if we're currently loading
    }

    // Hide details and stop, if the details are shown
    if(detailsRow.length > 0) {
      detailsRow.remove();
      return;
    }

    // insert cached details and stop, if possible
    if(clickedRow.data("details")) {
      clickedRow.data("details").insertAfter(clickedRow);
      return;
    }

    // if we get this far, we'll need to load the details, so:

    // show the loading message
    loadingRow = $('<tr class="loading"><td colspan="3">Loading...</td></tr>').insertAfter(clickedRow);

    // fetch details (using the deferred/promise API)
    xhr = $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_detailed.php",
      data: { id: id },
      cache: true
    });

    // add details when they've loaded
    xhr.done(function (html) {
      // I'm skipping the if(html) check, since the server should
      // return an error code if there's an error. And if so, this
      // done-handler will never be called anyway
      detailsRow = $(html).insertAfter(clickedRow);
      clickedRow.data("details", detailsRow);
    });

    // remove the loading row regardless of how the ajax request went
    xhr.always(function (html) {
      loadingRow.remove();
    });
  });
});
```

The PHP also looks iffy to me, but it's been a long time since I had to work with PHP, so I won't comment.

<strike>I will say though, that you're extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. For instance, if I send an id value of `0'; DROP DATABASE bf4; DROP USER bf4;` to your ajax_detailed.php script, it'll permanently delete your entire database and remove the database user. You *may* want to look into that...</strike>

Ignore the above - I had overlooked the call to `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Okay I'll definitely need to refactor my code more into functions, thanks for the comments. As for SQL injection, the `mysql_real_escape_string` will cover that. However the code is definitely not 100% secure.

Comment: @skiwi ah, I actually overlooked the call to `mysql_real_escape_string` - sorry (but note that that function has been deprecated)

Comment: If `$_GET['id']` is numeric, better cast it to an `int` instead of using `mysql_real_escape_string`.